# Why can't an extension of a Nullable<T> be used on a value of type T?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, nullable

I have an extension method:

```
public static int DoStuff(this MyEnum? enumValue) 
{
  ...
}
```

I want to invoke it on a value of `MyEnum` which is known to be not null:

```
MyEnum enumVal = ...
var x = enumVal.DoStuff(); // compiler error!
```

Error:

> error CS1928: 'MyEnum' does not contain a definition for 'DoStuff' and the best extension method overload 'MyExtensions.DoStuff(MyEnum?)' has some invalid arguments

I can work around it by declaring an overload of the extension:

```
 public static int DoStuff(this MyEnum enumValue)
 {
     return DoStuff((MyEnum?)enumValue); 
 }
```

Alternatively, I can invoke the extension class explicitly:

```
var x = MyExtensions.DoStuff(enumVal);
```

But this is non-intuitive. Why can't an extension of a `Nullable<T>` accept a value of type `T`, just like any normal method signature can?

Comment: cause `MyEnum` is not nullable

Comment: they aren't the same type.

Comment: Besides a `Nullable<T>` is definitely not a `T`.

Comment: @Rahul if I have a normal method `void DoStuff(MyEnum? enumVal) {}`, I can call it passing a value of type `MyEnum`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please note my edit: the question is why extension methods won't work on type `T`, when `T` is a valid argument for a parameter of type `Nullable<T>`?

Comment: @ShaulBehr that's *not* the same. You can also use `MyStaticClass.DoStuff(enumValue)` the same way. This works because the value is *converted* to `Nullable<MyEnum>`. Extension methods work on the concrete type though. The compiler is looking for extension methods that match the type exactly, not through implicit conversions

Comment: I think the language spec says so, but the wording is fairly thick.  It demands an *implicit identity* conversion in order to consider an extension method.  But this requires an implicit nullable conversion, a different animal.  Well, regardless, it ain't going to happen without a (MyEnum?) cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, extension methods (in contrast to method arguments) don't consider implicit conversions. And `MyEnum? value = nonNullableMyEnumValue` is using the implicit conversion, it is not the same type. You would run into the same situation with any other implicitly convertible type.